# Pull string from text file and rename the file using that text. For /F? Delims?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

Hello I am a little out of my depth here so hence the question. I have tried reading past post but due to my unfamiliarity I am unable to adapt other solutions into mine. I also don't really have proper code in place but I'm hoping that because my question seems simple maybe someone can help me or direct me. Thank you.

I have a program that exports EDI data into a file called FOUT_R.edi and I need a batch script that will look into the file, pull the string from line 4 value 3 and line 7 value 3 and then rename the file using the combined values. The values are asterisks delimited. Below is a sample...

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*JK60           *ZZ*     MFG *:
GS*IN*JK60*     MFG*20170223*1531*1*X*004010
ST*810*0001
BIG*20170223*237454
CUR*SE*CAD
REF*SI*238972
N1*ST*VEHICULOS COMERCIALES MEXICO S.A. DE C.V*92*065
N1*SU*METAL*92*JK60
DTM*011*20170223
```

So in the end I want the file name to read
`"237454 VEHICULOS COMERCIALES MEXICO S.A. DE C.V.edi"`
(.edi being the file extension). Again not sure what I'm doing, my starter scripts look like this

```
for /f "delims=*" %%fname1 IN (FOUT_R.edi) DO ren FOUT_R.edi %%fname1.edi
```

but it's obviously wrong it was just a starting spot for me but I realize now that this is out of my league.

Can someone please help or direct me to a site where the most inexperienced scripters can be explained in baby steps?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided the name in line 7 doesn't contain colons, this should do:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FileName=FOUT_R.edi"
set "NewName="
for /f "tokens=4 delims=:*" %%A in (
  'findstr /N "^" "%FileName%" ^|findstr "^4: ^7:"'
) Do Set "NewName=!NewName! %%A"
Echo Ren "%FileName%" "%NewName:~1%.edi"
timeout -1
```

If the output looks ok, remove the `Echo`

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "filename=FOUT_R.edi"

for /F "skip=3 tokens=3 delims=*" %%a in (%filename%) do set "Line4value3=%%a" & goto break1
:break1

for /F "skip=6 tokens=3 delims=*" %%a in (%filename%) do set "Line7value3=%%a" & goto break2
:break2

ren %filename% %Line4value3%%Line7value3%.edi
```

Sorry, no explanations; look for they yourself: open a command-prompt session and type the command followed by `/?`.

Note that if the file name may contain spaces, it must be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I couldn't get this working, it kept giving me a syntax error. I tried to remove the brackets in set "filename=FOUT_R.edi" and that didn't help and then I put them just on set filename="FOUT_R.edi" which allowed the script to run but it just called the file ".edi" without the brackets so essentially there was no file name. Not sure how to get it working.

Comment: You'll have to change the `ren`command to `ren "%filename%" "%Line4value3%%Line7value3%.edi"`